# PHP version is not the same

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

I had a problem with this code

```
class Crop
{
    const TYPE = ['main_crop', 'detail_crop', 'common_crop', 'list_crop'];
}

var_dump(Crop::TYPE);
```

Problem was that my PHP version was below 5.6
I managed to fix it by upgrading it.

So `php -i` is giving me `PHP Version => 7.0.16-4+deb.sury.org~trusty+1`.

Now I have a server running. Using `phpinfo()` I am getting back `PHP Version 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.21`, and because of it my code from above is not working.

I am using Laravel and using commands `composer upgrade`, `composer install` are not installing new php version. It doesn't matter what version I put in `"php":"xxx"`.

composer.json :

```
{
    "name": "laravel/lumen",
    "description": "The Laravel Lumen Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel", "lumen"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.6.0",
        "laravel/lumen-framework": "5.2.*",
        "vlucas/phpdotenv": "~2.2",
        "venturecraft/revisionable": "^1.27",
         "doctrine/dbal": "^2.5",
        "nicolaslopezj/searchable": "^1.9",
        "sofa/eloquence": "^5.2",
        "intervention/image": "^2.3",
        "ivanlemeshev/laravel5-cyrillic-slug": "^1.0",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "~6.0",
        "sngrl/sphinxsearch": "dev-master",
        "graylog2/gelf-php": "^1.5"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "~4.0"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        },
        "files": [
            "app/Helpers/Helper.php"
        ]
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "classmap": [
            "tests/",
            "database/"
        ]
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "php -r \"copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ]
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Composer is a php package manager. You cannot upgrade php with it. The `require: php > 5.6` part just indicates that the packages require php 5.6 or higher or you might run into issues. It is up to you to make sure your php version is correct.

Comment: I think you currently have (at least) 2 versions of php installed on your server - 5.5.9 and 7. From your post I assume your Apache (nginx?) is using 5.5.9 while your CLI uses 7. I believe that's where you're having problems.

Comment: And how can I change the php version othat apache is using? Any useful post or link

Comment: I think this question is better suited for sysadmins (has nothing to do with Laravel or composer). I don't know the answer.